# How to use spare wifi router as wifi extender

Tags: router, internet, wireless-networking

I have a spare wifi router other than the one that I use , I'm wondering whether it's possible to use spare router as wifi extender or repeater.

Has anyone ever done like this before ?

Any kind of leads or suggestions are welcome

Comment: This is not the correct place for this question, but yes. Some router default configurations will let you put it in Repeater mode, but often you need DD-WRT to "open up" the vendor's default firmware into something more useful. You'll need to find a guide on setting up Repeater mode, and maybe one on applying DD-WRT to your router if you need extra features.

Comment: Yes, it is done all the time.  Exactly how depends on your routers.

Comment: @FredricShope I was writing up my answer while you were writing your essentially identical comment.

Comment: I didn't want to post an answer since I don't think this is a DIY.SE question. I'll upvote yours, though :)

Comment: It is marginally on-topic. Wiring up a router (how to fish the cables, etc.) would definitely be on-topic. Remove the wires...

Comment: They have WIFI routers now? What on earth for? Can you adjust the RPM with your phone? Also, how many horsepower is it and what size collet?

Comment: I've not heard of the term "repeater mode"  but it sounds like bridge mode. I'm no IT expert, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: @George Repeater mode tries to be a mesh network, bridge mode just acts as a wireless link between two routers, so different uses.

Comment: In practice I have found that without a lot of setting fiddling and likely new firmware download and more fiddling, it's difficult to get the extender/repeater function to work properly. Many times this is the fault of el cheapo client devices that still see the two or more routers as separate unconnected access points. Just add a 2nd wifi network/ssid with your 2nd router, even if the backhaul is through your first router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. However, it is quite likely that the built-in software (firmware) won't do it. Take a look at [dd-wrt](https://dd-wrt.com/). This is replacement firmware that works on a lot of commercial routers, and provides a lot of additional features including [repeater](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers) functionality.

Comment: Thanks , seems like it's possible with this.